# iptables and Docker - allow only specific port mappings

Tags: iptables, docker

I have a server that runs docker containers. The server has 2 ips, a public ip (on interface `enp0s8`) and a private ip (on interface `tun0`, which is only accessible through a vpn). I want to configure iptables in a way to only allow access for ports 80 and 443 through the public interface but allow all ports through the vpn interface.

Exactly I try to do the following:

- Run a HAProxy Container with port-mappings 80:80, 443:443 (Should be accessible from public ip)
- Run a PhpMyAdmin Container with port-mapping 8080:80 (Should only be accessible from VPN)

I tried it by adding the following rules to iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -P ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i enp0s8 -j DROP
```

But the phpmyadmin container on port 8080 is still reachable from both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the docker network config. Typically you need to tweak `iptables -I FORWARD ...` chain only.

The `iptables -I INPUT -i enp0s8` only catches packets that appear on `enp0s8` and have IP addresses matching `ip addr show dev enp0s8`, so it won't catch typical docker traffic.

Comment: You are correct. I missed the `-t nat` entreis that docker adds to iptables. It appears, that docker adds rules to the `PREROUTING` chain which include already the port mapping. So a requtest to [host:8080] will appear as [container:80] in the `FORWARD`chain. That makes it impossible to match for [host:8080] in the FORWARD chain.

Comment: @Schlangguru If my answer doesn't make much sense, please paste your comment as a self-answer and ping me, I'll gladly delete.